# ASP.NET WebApi versioning not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, api-versioning

I'm trying to implement api versioning following this tutorial. So in my startup I have:

```
var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver()
{
    ConstraintMap =
    {
        ["apiVersion"] = typeof( ApiVersionRouteConstraint )
    }
};

configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
configuration.AddApiVersioning()
```

and my controllers:

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/my")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
public class MyV1Controller 

[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/my")]
[ApiVersion("3.0")]
public class MyV3Controller
```

When I request for http://localhost/api/v1.0/my I get an error

```
Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.\r\n\r\nThe request has found the following matching controller types: \r\nMyV1Controller\r\nMyV2Controller
```

Could you please advice how to make controller versioning to work?

Comment: Your "V1" controller can have multiple versions? Would the V1 controller be one version? ...Why two attributes?

Comment: This may be an issue with dot in your url.

Comment: My api consist of few controllers. While there was a version 2 that affected other conrollers there were no changes made to MyV1Controller. So I just increased the number.

Answer (score 1):

I took a break and I remembered that in my project I have a custom IHttpControllerSelector implementation which extends DefaultHttpControllerSelector.

```
configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new ApiControllerSelector(config));
```

After I removed it versioning started to work. 
Executing configuration.AddApiVersioning sets ApiVersionControllerSelector in ServicesContainer. It was accidently replaced with my custom implementation.